# select other record using subquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I try to list out all customer records with first date of order

**Table Customers**

```
customer_id | customer_name
    1       +    John
    2       +    Brad
```

**Table Orders**

```
order_id  | customer_id | date
   1      +      1      + 2013-10-12 01:00:00
   2      +      1      + 2013-11-18 09:00:00
   3      +      2      + 2013-11-21 02:00:00
```

**MySQL**

```
$get_ch_raw = "select c.*, a.*, ch.* from `customers` c  left join `admin` a on 
a.admin_id=c.admin_id left join `call_history` ch on 
ch.customer_id=c.customers_id 
order by c.customers_id desc"
```

and the result should be like this :

```
1       +    John    +   2013-10-12 01:00:00
2       +    Brad    +   2013-11-21 02:00:00
```

I'm not sure how to select the first of order using subquery in this situation.

Comment: I'm assuming that table `admin` should actually be `orders`, right?

Comment: urmmm no, admin is beauty consultant, i dont want to list out all table here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, MIN(o.date) date FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o USING (customer_id)
GROUP BY c.customer_id
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd3dd9/1).